# How to simulate shortest Path finder/planner and dynamic obstacle detection in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-sensor, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am a beacholers student choose final year project to be shortest path finder and planner including dynamic obstacle detection (A robotic Car). As i am new to gazebo, looking at some official tutorials i got to know how to make a car move. But where should i exactly start from, i dont know how to even avoid static obstacles.

Please guide me, where could i get some extra help ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4199/how-to-simulate-shortest-path-finder/planner-and-dynamic-obstacle-detection-in-gazebo/) by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

implementing such stuff has to be done by your own controllers gazebo only provides the physical simulation.

To recognize static obstacles you can use Sensors like the laser scanners. A very primitive approach would be if you detect an object on the right side you move left...(This is probably not the best approach cause you might get stuck in corners etc...)

For path planning you will need some kind of other representation(a map) of your world. This map could be used for different path planning algorithms. If you want to use a map you have to now if this is generated in runtime or if it is know to the robot before you start. If you have to create a map at runtime you might want to take a look at SLAM packages...
After you got a map you can use common path planners with it. Which is the best planner for your purposes is not an easy question. It depends highly on the environment your in, on the size of your environment, if there are moving obstacles etc, maybe the SBPL or OMPL Planners have an algorithm that suits your needs...

It might be a good idea to look at ROS for some of this things, but it is not mandatory...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on 2013-09-18**:
Thank you !!
I might consult you when i get stuck :)

**Comment by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on 2014-11-24**:
hey did u able to control the braking system of car (polaris) in gazebo ? Any help would be appreciated . Thanks!